# $scope model in angular is not updating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

I've been working with angular, the thing is that I put this ng-model which is a text input and at the same time I use it with this autocomplete directive, the problem is that I want to change the value of the input once that this select someting from the autocomplete, but instead just puts the number when what I need is the description, the thing is that when I put all the number it actaully changes it to the way I want, could somebody help me, this is the code
   $scope.trailer = {

```
options: {
    minLength:2,
    html: true,
    source:"controllers/search.php?catalogo=trailers",

    select: function(event, ui){
      console.log(ui);       
      //$(this).val(ui.item.desc+' '+ui.item.clave).change();
      $scope.formData.trailerid = ui.item.id;
      $scope.formData.trailerclave = ui.item.clave;
      $scope.formData.trailerdueno = ui.item.propietario;
      $scope.formData.trailer = ui.item.desc;//+' '+ui.item.clave; 

      return false;
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      if (ui.item == null) {
          $scope.formData.trailerid = 0 ;
          $scope.formData.trailerdueno = '';
          $scope.formData.trailerclave = '';
          $scope.formData.trailer = '';
      }
    }
},
methods: {}

 }
```

and the html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control trailer" ng-model="formData.trailer" ui-autocomplete = "trailer" />
                                        <span class="help-block">{{formData.trailer}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find if I'm using a function or event that's part of an external plugin not having to do with Angular I need to wrap anything within them in $scope.$apply(function(){});

```
options: {
minLength:2,
html: true,
source:"controllers/search.php?catalogo=trailers",

select: function(event, ui){
 $scope.$apply(function(){
  console.log(ui);       
  //$(this).val(ui.item.desc+' '+ui.item.clave).change();
  $scope.formData.trailerid = ui.item.id;
  $scope.formData.trailerclave = ui.item.clave;
  $scope.formData.trailerdueno = ui.item.propietario;
  $scope.formData.trailer = ui.item.desc;//+' '+ui.item.clave; 
 });
  return false;
},
change: function (event, ui) {
  if (ui.item == null) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.formData.trailerid = 0 ;
      $scope.formData.trailerdueno = '';
      $scope.formData.trailerclave = '';
      $scope.formData.trailer = '';
    });
  }
}
},
methods: {}

 }
```

Comment: Nothing happened :(, do you think I have to put inside the ui-autoomplete directive?, or there is a way for initialize the scope in the controller?, thx for you kind response

Comment: Thank you, apparently the problem was in the change function , I just added this '$scope.formData.trailer = ui.item.desc;' to the begin of it, thank you so much for your answers